# Override  - (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, comparison, nsobject

I want to override this method for comparing two objects.

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
```

Calling function

```
-(void)overridemethod(

custom class object1 isEqual:  custom class object2
```

)

definition of function

```
let suppose comparing the date parameter of two objects. Then how can i do that.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear, please can you explain what you are attempting to achieve?  Do you just want a different name for the method (then create an NSObject category), or do you want to change the format of the language (then make a #define macro), or something else?

Comment: explain more..the function you want to override ..just check whether two objects are equal and return a BOOL stating yes for equal or NO for equal..what functionality you want to change??

Comment: not clear? u wanna override for all objects? or for a custom class?

Comment: In the function i want to compare a object1 parameter to object2 parameter, like as object1 date parameter to compare with object2 date parameter.

Comment: Hi edited my question, hope now it will be clear to you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

an implementation will often take this form:

```
@interface MONInteger : NSObject
{
@private
    int value;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) int value;

@end

@implementation MONInteger
...
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    // MONInteger allows a comparison to NSNumber
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSNumber * other = object;
        return self.value == other.intValue;
    }
    else if (![object isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
        return NO;
    }
    MONInteger * other = object;
    return self.value == other.value;
}

@end
```

Comment: to compare strings, you would often use `-[NSString isEqualToString:]`.

Comment: i edited my question hope you would now understand what i am asking for?

Comment: then the implementation of `isEqual:` will be different - for starters, you would change `return self.value == other.value;` from the example above to something like `return [self.date isEqual:other.date];`. however, it's difficult to tell what *exactly* you're asking for -- there are many missing details. at any rate, your comparison logic will often vary quite a bit from class to class.

Comment: I wouldn't bother checking if the class is the same. If the class is not the same I want compile error start popping out.

Comment: @HaryantoCiu it's too late. the type's already been erased by the method signature when using `isEqual:`, so the dynamic type-checking is needed if you want to know how to interact with that object (or even implement) `isEqual:`'. nor does objc offer some form of dynamic overloading. ideally, you would just declare and use a method which qualified a type -- this is why one would favor typed comparators (e.g. `isEqualToString:` and `isEqualToData:`) when they know the type. but a compiler error isn't going to pop up when `-[NSObject isEqual:]` is used.

Comment: Not exactly compiler error. But it'll raise some exception. Things like this object doesn't satisfy this method or selector.

Comment: @HaryantoCiu `-[NSObject isEqual:]` is *intended* to be a heterogenous object to object comparator -- it doesn't make sense for a type to reject the parameter based on its type in this context.

Comment: I think it's intended to be homogenous. It's just that in Objective-c there is no way to accept anything else than (id) due to lack of <template> feature in objective c. If it's not (id) what should it be put? If we put the class names then we will need a different function for different class and things don't really get overridden.

Comment: @HaryantoCiu it's *not* intended to be homogenous - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW61   --- of course, you can always define your own object comparison method with different semantics, which is intended to be homogenous.